# Django: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cafe_name'

Tags: django

Hey I am trying to return a set of objects that belong to "friends" the logged in user follows and are within a specific geographic space. But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cafe_name'
```

views.py

```
def get_friends(request):
    template_name = 'testingland/electra.html'
    neLat = request.GET.get('neLat', None)
    neLng = request.GET.get('neLng', None)
    swLat = request.GET.get('swLat', None)
    swLng = request.GET.get('swLng', None)
    ne = (neLat, neLng)
    sw = (swLat, swLng)

    xmin = float(sw[1])
    ymin = float(sw[0])
    xmax = float(ne[1])
    ymax = float(ne[0])
    bbox = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

    geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)

    friends = UserConnections.objects.filter(
    follower=request.user
    ).values_list('followed__pk', flat=True)

    mapCafes.objects.filter(
        geolocation__coveredby=geom,
        uservenue__user_list__user__pk__in=friends
    ).distinct()

    return JsonResponse([
            [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address, cafe.geolocation.y, cafe.geolocation.x]
            for cafe in friends
    ], safe=False)
```

Models

```
class mapCafes(models.Model): 
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cafe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_long = models.FloatField()
    cafe_lat = models.FloatField()
    geolocation = models.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    venue_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image_embed = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'a_cafes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cafe_name

[...]

class UserConnections(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /electra/get_friends/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/anybody1/testingland/views.py", line 198, in get_friends
    return JsonResponse([
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/anybody1/testingland/views.py", line 199, in <listcomp>
    [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address, cafe.geolocation.y, cafe.geolocation.x]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cafe_name'
[04/May/2021 10:08:56] "GET /electra/get_friends/?neLat=-37.745828313897285&neLng=145.02699006270083&swLat=-37.76869671883467&swLng=144.98679313729914 HTTP/1.1" 500 68694
Internal Server Error: /electra/get_friends/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/anybody1/testingland/views.py", line 198, in get_friends
    return JsonResponse([
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/anybody1/testingland/views.py", line 199, in <listcomp>
    [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address, cafe.geolocation.y, cafe.geolocation.x]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cafe_name'
[04/May/2021 10:12:31] "GET /electra/get_friends/?neLat=-37.745828313897285&neLng=145.02699006270083&swLat=-37.76869671883467&swLng=144.98679313729914 HTTP/1.1" 500 68809
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through `friends` which is a list of int primary keys, I think you meant to do it  through `map_cafes`

try something like:

```
    cafes = mapCafes.objects.filter(
        geolocation__coveredby=geom,
        uservenue__user_list__user__pk__in=friends
    ).distinct()

    return JsonResponse([
            [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address, cafe.geolocation.y, cafe.geolocation.x]
            for cafe in cafes 
    ], safe=False)
```

Comment: Thank you that helped! How would I return the "friend" data as well - so I could use it at the front end (eg. show which friend likes what cafe etc.)

Comment: you can add to json_response { 'cafes': [ ...] , 'friends': friends }

Comment: Nice thanks just to clarify, putting a list comprehension inside a dict: ```{'cafes':[cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address, cafe.geolocation.y, cafe.geolocation.x] for cafe in cafes, 'friends':friends}```